# Summarise the time difference per day

Tags: r, time, dplyr

Data example:

```
ID <- as.factor(c('1', '1', '1', '1', 
                  '1', '1', '2', '2',
                  '2'))

n1 <- as.factor(c('yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 
                  'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes',
                  'yes'))

n2 <- as.POSIXct(c(NA, '2020-04-01  17:49:21', 
                   '2020-04-02 11:00:41', '2020-04-03 08:01:11', 
                   '2020-04-03 14:34:02', '2020-04-04 17:20:04',
                   NA, '2020-04-03 16:49:43',
                   '2020-04-04 10:00:31'))

n3 <- as.POSIXct(c(NA, '2020-04-01  17:50:12', 
                   '2020-04-02 11:01:32', '2020-04-03 08:02:43', 
                   '2020-04-03 14:35:01', '2020-04-04 17:21:13',
                   NA, '2020-04-03 16:50:21',
                   '2020-04-04 10:01:15'))

n4 <- as.POSIXct(c('2020-04-01 10:42:34', '2020-04-01 19:07:23', 
                   '2020-04-02 12:01:32', '2020-04-03 09:03:54',
                   '2020-04-03 15:41:12', '2020-04-04 18:22:25', 
                   '2020-04-03 15:43:26', '2020-04-03 18:07:56',
                   '2020-04-04 11:34:36'))

n5<- as.character(c('2020-04-01', '2020-04-01', 
                    '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03',
                    '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', 
                    '2020-04-03', '2020-04-03',
                    '2020-04-04'))
date <- data.frame(ID,
                   n1,
                   n2,
                   n3,
                   n4,
                   n5)

> date
 ID  n1                  n2                  n3                  n4         n5
1  1 yes                <NA>                <NA> 2020-04-01 10:42:34 2020-04-01
2  1  no 2020-04-01 17:49:21 2020-04-01 17:50:12 2020-04-01 19:07:23 2020-04-01
3  1 yes 2020-04-02 11:00:41 2020-04-02 11:01:32 2020-04-02 12:01:32 2020-04-02
4  1 yes 2020-04-03 08:01:11 2020-04-03 08:02:43 2020-04-03 09:03:54 2020-04-03
5  1  no 2020-04-03 14:34:02 2020-04-03 14:35:01 2020-04-03 15:41:12 2020-04-03
6  1 yes 2020-04-04 17:20:04 2020-04-04 17:21:13 2020-04-04 18:22:25 2020-04-04
7  2 yes                <NA>                <NA> 2020-04-03 15:43:26 2020-04-03
8  2 yes 2020-04-03 16:49:43 2020-04-03 16:50:21 2020-04-03 18:07:56 2020-04-03
9  2 yes 2020-04-04 10:00:31 2020-04-04 10:01:15 2020-04-04 11:34:36 2020-04-04
```

How is it possible to summarise the time difference for each day from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59, separated by ID under following pattern. For example, when n1 is "yes" I need the time difference between n4 (row 1) and n2 (row2) and when n1 is "no" between n4 (row 1) and n3 (row 2) and so on.

An attempt to solve the problem.

```
date %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(behaviour.length = ifelse(n1 == "yes", 
                                difftime(n2, 
                                         lag(n4), 
                                         units = "secs"), 
                                difftime(n3, 
                                         lag(n4), 
                                         units = "secs"))) %>% 
  group_by(ID,
           n5) %>% 
  mutate(behaviour.length.per.day = sum(behaviour.length)) %>% 
  select(ID,
         behaviour.length.per.day) -> 
> date
# Groups:   ID, n5 [6]
  ID    n5         behaviour.length.per.day
  <fct> <fct>                         <dbl>
1 1     2020-04-01                       NA
2 1     2020-04-01                       NA
3 1     2020-04-02                    57198
4 1     2020-04-03                    95446
5 1     2020-04-03                    95446
6 1     2020-04-04                    92332
7 2     2020-04-03                       NA
8 2     2020-04-03                       NA
9 2     2020-04-04                    57155
```

But than their occur 3 major problems.

The first one is for each ID the first observation is always n4, so n2 and n3 are in the beginning every time NA. According to that the observation start constantly contains NA. Which is wrong because their wasnt behaviour to observe, I later like to summarise.

The second one, days occurs twice in the output.

The third and biggest problem is, that the calculations of the time difference are based on two days and not only on one. An example for that is time difference between column n4 & row 2 and n2 & row 3. This are calculations between two days. I would like to stop the calculation for the first day at 23:59:59 and start again for the second day at 00:00:00. So that I get the total length of the behaviour observed within 24 hour interval.

Hopefully you can help to solve the problem. Thanks.

Wanted results:

```
ID      n5                  behaviour.length.per.day        
1 1     2020-04-01                    43214
2 1     2020-04-02                    82748
3 1     2020-04-03                    78665
4 1     2020-04-04                    82658
5 2     2020-04-03                    25100
6 2     2020-04-04                    80744
```

Explanation how the wanted results has to be calculated. (It is not a code.)

```
row 1 = (date$n3[2] - date$n4[1]) + (23:59:59 - date$n4[2]) = 43214 sec
row 2 = (date$n2[3] - 00:00:00) + (23:59:59 - date$n4[3]) = 82748 sec 
row 3 = (date$n2[4] - 00:00:00) + (date$n3[5]- date$n4[4]) + (24:00:00 - n4[5] = 78665 sec
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you expect? I'm not sure I'm understanding your description correctly.

Comment: Does the wanted output and the explanation how to calculated helps?